# Get active menu itemid in Joomla using javascript

Tags: javascript, joomla, menuitem

I need to use javascript to get the itemid of the current page in Joomla. Is there a way to do this? The urls are sef so I cant just use the url...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No mention of version, but I've used this in the past with the PHP.  There's no direct javascript way, so you'll need to echo that into your script, or put it into a hidden form field, or some other mechanism.

```
$currentMenuId = JSite::getMenu()->getActive()->id ;
```

Comment: Ok, great, I'll put it in a hidden input then. Thats fine by me. Thanks!

Comment: Accepting my answer would be REAL thankyou, lol, and give you more credibility when you ask future questions - good luck